# flex 4 how to implement a custom accordion that can open multiple tabs

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, custom-component

i implement a container by extending SkinnableContainer, but when i use the container in a mxml application, i can't add components with diffrent namespace into the container.

```
<local:MyCustomContainer>
    <s:Label text="aaa"/>   //error occurs at this line.
</local:MyCustomContainer>
```

Comment: Unable to resolves "<s:Label>" to the component...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try 
     `<local:Label text="aaa"/`>